# Regexes to match 3 specific places of a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm stuck trying to find a way to get 3 sections of a string without using splitting and some weird things. The target string looks like this one:

```
BLABLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLA - BLABLA BLABLA (BLABLA1 BLABLA2)
```

I need to extract three parts as follows:

1) BLABLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLA (left part)

2) BLABLA BLABLA (middle part)

3) BLABLA1 BLABLA2 (right part between parentheses)

What I've done by now is:

```
var text = "BLABLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLA - BLABLA BLABLA (BLABLA1 BLABLA2)";

var left = Regex.Matches(text, @"([^)]*)-");
var middle = Regex.Matches(text, @"-([^)]*)\(");
var right = Regex.Matches(text, @"\(([^)]*)\)");

Console.WriteLine(left[0]);
Console.WriteLine(middle[0]);
Console.WriteLine(right[0]);
```

Output:

```
BLABLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLA -
- BLABLA BLABLA (
(BLABLA1 BLABLA2)
```

Seems to work but the output is containing the delimiters and I just want the raw content.

Comment: `string.Split(new [] {'-','(',')')`

Comment: @TheGeneral missing `}`

Comment: Use `Regex.Split(s, @"\s+-\s+|\s+\(([^()]+)\)$").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this single regex and get all three values from three groups,

```
^(.+)\s+-\s+(.+)\s+\(([^()]+)\)$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Matches start of input
- `(.+)` - Matches and captures any character one or more times and just stops before a space(s) and hyphen and places in group1
- `\s+-\s+` - Matches whitespace(s) followed by hyphen `-` and again whitespace(s) and excludes them from being part of any group capture as these are not required
- `(.+)` - Matches the next sequence of characters one or more and captures in group2
- `\s+\(` - Matches one or more whitespace followed by literal `(`
- `([^()]+)` - Matches one or more any character other than `(` or `)` and captures in group3
- `\)$` - Followed by literal `)` and end of string

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zAn2hN/1)**

[C# Code demo](https://rextester.com/MPDQ44351)

```
var text = "BLABLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLA - BLABLA BLABLA (BLABLA1 BLABLA2)";

var match = Regex.Match(text, @"^(.+)\s+-\s+(.+)\s+\(([^()]+)\)$");
Console.WriteLine("left: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine("middle: " + match.Groups[2].Value);
Console.WriteLine("right: " + match.Groups[3].Value);
```

Prints,

```
left: BLABLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLA
middle: BLABLA BLABLA
right: BLABLA1 BLABLA2
```

**Edit:**
As per your comment, if the last part of string that is contained in parenthesis can be optional, then you can use this regex, where third group is optional.

```
^(.+)\s+-\s+(.+?)\s*(?:\(([^()]+)\))?$
```

**[Regex Demo with group3 being optional](https://regex101.com/r/zAn2hN/3)**

[Updated C# demo](https://rextester.com/NCXWZ67752)

```
var text = "BLABLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLA - BLABLA BLABLA (BLABLA1 BLABLA2)";

var match = Regex.Match(text, @"^(.+)\s+-\s+(.+)\s+\(([^()]+)\)$");
Console.WriteLine("left: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine("middle: " + match.Groups[2].Value);
Console.WriteLine("right: " + match.Groups[3].Value);

text = "BLABLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLA - BLABLA BLABLA";

match = Regex.Match(text, @"^(.+)\s+-\s+(.+?)\s*(?:\(([^()]+)\))?$");
Console.WriteLine("\nleft: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine("middle: " + match.Groups[2].Value);
Console.WriteLine("right: " + match.Groups[3].Value);
```

Prints,

```
left: BLABLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLA
middle: BLABLA BLABLA
right: BLABLA1 BLABLA2

left: BLABLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLA
middle: BLABLA BLABLA
right:
```

Comment: Could you please modify this regex to also match a string that does not contain the right part, I just noticed that scenario can occur, some strings contains the () and others dont

Comment: @AnonDev: Sure, quite easy. Just need to make that group optional by putting `?` at the end of group. Let me update my post.